# Is "Behalves" A Proper Plural of "Behalf"?

Tags: word-usage, agreement

The following sentence appears in a [syllabus of a decision of the United States Court of Appeals for the 9th Circuit](http://cdn.ca9.uscourts.gov/datastore/opinions/2017/10/10/16-15606.pdf) (at page 3):

> The panel affirmed the district court’s dismissal of Longoria’s
>   family-members’ § 1983 claims. The panel held that only Longoria’s
>   estate could bring a § 1983 for the violation of his Fourth Amendment
>   rights; his family members had no standing to sue on their own
>   **behalves**.

My question relates to the correctness of the word in bold faced type in that sentence. I would have written that sentence: " . . . ; no family member of Longoria had standing to sue on his or her behalf." And, I have never seen the word "behalves" used in writing as a plural of "behalf."

Is "behalves" a recognized plural of behalf in a context like the sentence quoted above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Behalves was historically used as the plural of behalf.](http://www.word-detective.com/2012/08/behalf-behalves/) It is sometimes also spelled behalfs.  While it is not commonly used today, you can occasionally still find the rare usage here and there.

Here is the entry on [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/behalves)

[But if you look at the ngram viewer graph, you can see both versions had a sporadic usage and were never truly that popular.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=behalves%2Cbehalfs&year_start=1650&year_end=1900&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbehalves%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbehalfs%3B%2Cc0)

Here are a few usages of the word in print.

> ...but now wee sue in your Lordshipps behalves... [(1662)](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=CfAxAQAAMAAJ&q=%22behalves%22&dq=%22behalves%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiE5Jny7unWAhXBVrwKHRnQC4kQ6AEIKDAA)
>
> ...rather than that they should occasion a fruitless and calamitous
>   confusion in their behalfs. [(1689)](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=Big-AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA47&dq=%22behalfs%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiJyIT07unWAhVLE7wKHdkFAp8Q6AEINDAC#v=onepage&q=%22behalfs%22&f=false)
>
> ...I'll bring you where he is aboard, tender your persons to his presence, whisper him in your behalfs. [(1863)](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=bd9DAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA406&dq=%22behalfs%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwib54jj7-nWAhVGxrwKHYfIC5kQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=%22behalfs%22&f=false)
>
> However, unlike many of the other survey categories, neither guy nor
>   gal was opposed to having their significant other make that cinematic
>   decision on their collective behalves. [(2003)](https://www.thefreelibrary.com/Who+Has+Better+Taste%3F+Men+and+Women+Agree+to+Disagree-a098891258)

Comment: The ngram viewer suggests that usage ended around 1875, plus or minus, despite being never really popular. I wonder if something happened then that changed common practice.

Comment: What's interesting to note is that "behalve" (note the singular) is a spelling that the OED has listed (used ME until the 15th century). For example, ["On Goddes behalve"](https://books.google.com/books?id=eaAuAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA198&lpg=PA198&dq="On+Goddes+behalve"). So I would imagine that there are plenty of results that predate what NGram will show you.

Comment: Is "behalve" singular?  One could easily input behalve into NGram as well to track it.

Comment: @KumaAra Yes, it's singular (because"Goddes" = "God's"). I don't think NGram will return good results though (I think most of the hits will be reprints or Dutch; the originals are too old). The [Middle English Dictionary](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/m/mec/med-idx?type=id&id=MED4497&egs=all&egdisplay=open) is worth a look though.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, behalves is quite correct as the plural of behalf.

[Behalf/Behalves (World Dictionary)](http://www.word-detective.com/2012/08/behalf-behalves/)

Not to be confused with the word 'behoves'.

[Behoves](https://www.google.co.uk/search?source=hp&q=behoves&oq=behoves&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0l10.1202.2351.0.3450.7.7.0.0.0.0.91.467.7.7.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.7.466...0i131k1.0.lOCsRrzFzvM)

Comment: Both your links go to behove/s

Comment: @Clare Apologies. Finger trouble. Sorted now and OK.